# How do I base64 encode a SHA1() string in a C program

Tags: c, base64, sha1

I want to verify passwords in a C program. The passwords are stored using the `sha1_base64()` Perl function [http://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA1](http://metacpan.org/pod/Digest%3a%3aSHA1)

I am trying to use `openssl/sha.h` and `b64.c` but the passwords do not match.

My C program is here http://pastebin.com/CPC1vYAK

The C code output:

```
[ram@darkstar c]$ ./sha1  password
W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9j0z8Q=
```

And the Perl code:

```
[ram@darkstar c]$ perl -MDigest::SHA -le 'print Digest::SHA::sha1_base64("password")'
W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g
```

Comment: Please inline the relevant parts of the source code directly in your question here.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have a

```
SHA1(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), obuf);
base64_encode(obuf,strlen(obuf),b64,100);
```

`strlen(obuf)` is wrong, because `obuf` contains raw binary data, which do not have a null terminator, so it will report a wrong length to `base64_encode`.

Since SHA-1 produces a digest of 20 bytes (as big as is `obuf`), you'll have to pass to `base64_encode` this size:

```
base64_encode(obuf,20,b64,100);
/* or (may be better if you later decide to change hashing algorithm) */
base64_encode(obuf,sizeof(obuf),b64,100);
```

Comment: Ok this seems to work fine .. I am just 0 filling the strings 
http://pastebin.com/LCvghszK

Comment: @Ram: it's still a stupid idea. Just ***avoid `strlen` when dealing with binary data***. You already know that it's 20 bytes long, I even provided 2 examples of the correction you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `strlen(obuf)` when you have a static buffer of 20 chars (160 bits) that can hold any binary data. `strlen` won't be right: if you have eight aligned bits to 0 it will break, and if no byte in your buffer is zero the behaviour will be undefined. Use `sizeof(obuf)` instead.